# Laravel - How to check if (SSH) Socket is Alive?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, laravel-5

I have a remote server with MySQL. On another server I need to connected to the remote MySQL (via Laravel 5.2).

For now in the server (Ubuntu 14.04) I connected manually with command:

```
ssh -N -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 -pXXX *****@serverName.com
```

This is working well, but after about an hour the connection lost.

How in Laravel (v5.2) can I check if the connection is alive, and if not connect automatically?

Comment: you could use netstat -tlpan, then look for a connection on the port you specified and it should be ESTABLISHED if the connection is still alive.

Comment: Yes i use for now like : 
`netstat -lpnt | grep 13306 | grep ssh`

Have a better way in Laravel to check this?

Comment: When Laravel did not even start the ssh session?  Not likely.  Laravel might be able to give you STDERR output if you used Laravel's SSH::run() method, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1) Use standard PHP command "system" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) with call check ssh port (through ssh/telent commands). Not sure that this method allows to direct restart the service.

2) Use async method: use console (bash/php) script for check ssh port and when it wasn't the "ssh not allowed" flag set in some database table and then you can check this field in the PHP code, and, if need, you can set some other database flag like "restart the ssh" and use Linux Cron for check this flag in database periodically and if it found the flag then restart the ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch PDOException in case if 'mysql gone away' or 'lost connection' and reconnect to the sever. The code can look like this:

```
        try {
            \DB::select("SELECT version()");
        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            if (in_array($e->getCode(), [2002, 2013, 2006])) {
                \DB::reconnect();
            }
        }
```

Most probably you will have to write your own wrapper on Laravel \DB::select, update, insert to make reconnection in one place.